# Natural number to Rational number and at the end POULET number

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Generalize / prove or disprove the following statement.

For any prime $p$ $>5$ and prime $q$, we get infinite natural numbers $N$ such that

$N$$= (q-1)/(p-1)$. If $N$ is rational, instead of natural number, then $pq$ is poulet number for $q > p$.
Could you please explain with illustrative example.

Comment: Nice question annaya !

Comment: What's a Poulet number?

Comment: A Poulet number is a Fermat pseudoprime to base 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arithmetic progression $a_N=(p-1)N+1$ contains infinitely many primes $q$ by Dirichlet. hence the first question has a positive answer. The second claim does not hold. For $(q,p)=(19,17)$ we have $N=9/8$, but $pq=323$ is not a Poulet number. In fact, the first Poulet number is $341$.

Comment: ! I am very happy with your second question answer by counter examples. But, I would like to know your first answer in more clear. How $a_N$ contains infinitely many primes $q$ by Direchlet? Please explain and relate to my first question. Once again thank you for answering my second question with great example.

Comment: Relation is $q=(p-1)N+1$ corresponds to $N=(q-1)/(p-1)$. Theorem of Dirichlet, see here:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions.

Comment: ! Thank you for your quick reply. I din't find any info on wiki. can you please explain...

Comment: ! kindly prove, how $a_n = q$ contains infinitely many primes?

Comment: Dietrich has given you the keyphrase, "Dirichlet's Theorem on primes in arithmetic progression" --- search for it!